# Минимальный доступ MSSQL для просмотра view представления

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите пожалуйста по правам доступа в MSSQL
требуется предоставить минимальные права через windows-аутентификацию- только просмотр определенного представления view.
Создаю с нуля пользователя в mapping указываю нужную бд
в roles, securables указано public
в securables в grant указано только Connect SQL

почему же с такими правами учетка может смотреть в
Server Objects>Linked Servers да еще при запросе получать данные из таблиц на которые у нее нет там прав ?

Comment: Надо права на `connect` и права на `select`. Кажись всё.

Comment: дак так и есть, но мне нравится что Server Objects>Linked Servers  пользователь может шариться, создавать запросы и видеть данные из прилинкованных серверов и их бд, причем это по минималке созданный пользователь, майкрософт чтоли так шалит )